# How do I call the stickynavbar function on the navigation wrapper in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site, and I've decided to finally use jquery, but having no skill in js, I got slightly stuck. I have no idea how to Call the stickyNavbar function on the navigation wrapper, nav tag or ul tag. Here's the code:

```html
$(function () {
    $('.header').stickyNavbar({
    activeClass: "active",          // Class to be added to highlight nav elements
    sectionSelector: "scrollto",    // Class of the section that is interconnected with nav links
    animDuration: 250,              // Duration of jQuery animation
    startAt: 0,                     // Stick the menu at XXXpx from the top of the this() (nav container)
    easing: "linear",               // Easing type if jqueryEffects = true, use jQuery Easing plugin to extend easing types - gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing
    animateCSS: true,               // AnimateCSS effect on/off
    animateCSSRepeat: false,        // Repeat animation everytime user scrolls
    cssAnimation: "fadeInDown",     // AnimateCSS class that will be added to selector
    jqueryEffects: false,           // jQuery animation on/off
    jqueryAnim: "slideDown",        // jQuery animation type: fadeIn, show or slideDown
    selector: "a",                  // Selector to which activeClass will be added, either "a" or "li"
    mobile: false,                  // If false nav will not stick under 480px width of window
    mobileWidth: 480,               // The viewport width (without scrollbar) under which stickyNavbar will not be applied (due usability on mobile devices)
    zindex: 9999,                   // The zindex value to apply to the element: default 9999, other option is "auto"
    stickyModeClass: "sticky",      // Class that will be applied to 'this' in sticky mode
    unstickyModeClass: "unsticky"   // Class that will be applied to 'this' in non-sticky mode
  });
});
```

And I now don't know where to put it in my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        
    <title>Sunny Bistro</title>
   
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
            
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Base%20CSS.css"> 
      
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
    
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        
   
    </head>
    
 

   
    
    
    <body>
 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/stickynavbar.js/1.3.4/jquery.stickyNavbar.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>var _nearplace=_nearplace||{};_nearplace.organization='0615ec61-9279-49ee-9d05-b021594eef39';_nearplace.widget='d2b48791-d4a8-439c-8a2f-c59d214275a3';window.nearplace||function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=!0;s.src='https://widget.nearplace.com/loader.js';document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){(document.scripts[0]||document.head).appendChild(s)})}();</script>

<div id="header" class="header">
   <nav id="nav">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li>
             <a href="#home">Home</a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#about">About</a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#services">Services</a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
        
 
        
           <section id="bottle">
        <article>
        <h6><img src="CSS/Images/SunnyBistro-8.png" ></h6>
        <h1>The Sunny Bistro</h1>   
        <h2>The sunny bistro</h2>   
        </article>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.3"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="story-freext">
        <article>
        
        </article>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.1"></div>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.5" data-fit="525"></div>
    </section>
    <section></section>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.scrolly.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.parallax').scrolly({bgParallax: true});
    });
</script>


    </body>


</html>
```

I'm quite new to this, so thanks in advance :)
My nav bar should look like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ueyl.png)
But it looks like this:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MneSR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, you need to clean your HTML. You've so many  that you don't need in your code.

To begin, import jQuery just before `</body>`. I've deleted in your `<head>` and `<body>` the lines for import jQuery because you don't need theses.

For your function stickynavbar, where do have found that function ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sunny Bistro</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Base%20CSS.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>



    <section id="bottle">
        <article>
            <h6><img src="CSS/Images/SunnyBistro-8.png"></h6>
            <h1>The Sunny Bistro</h1>
            <h2>The sunny bistro</h2>
        </article>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.3"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="story-freext">
        <article>

        </article>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.1"></div>
        <div class="parallax" data-velocity="-.5" data-fit="525"></div>
    </section>
    <section></section>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/stickynavbar.js/1.3.4/jquery.stickyNavbar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.header').stickyNavbar();
    })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My Navbar is looking strange even after I did everything I had to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MneSR.png. Do you know how to fix this? I found the function here: https://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/

Comment: I've edit the code in my previous answer. Can you try it ? I've deleted `scrolly` but don't worry, we can add it after

Comment: thank you! the navbar is finally sticking! the only problem: It's still just a bunch of text at the top. no decor. Could it be something with the CSS? https://i.imgur.com/RqcjH01.jpg

Comment: You want something more like a navbar ? Add theses lines in your css file :


`.header {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #nav  li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 50px;
    }`

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Now, if only I could remember how to change the colour

Comment: Change the color of the navbar ? 
`#nav { 
text-align: center;
background-color: green;
 }`

Instead of green, you can insert which Color you want or an hex code (eg: #00FF00)

Comment: You're welcome! If I can give you a little advice, check Bootstrap. You may find some amazing things
[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

@vlad I would suggest rather of using plugin. It can be achieved through simple script.
Please add the below script in the bottom and css in stylesheet.

```
<style>
.stickey-header{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:40px;
}
</style>
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
   $('.header').addClass('sticky-header');
} else {
   $('.header').removeClass('newClass');
}
});
```